# Spring Cloud Gateway OAuth2 with Spring Security OAuth2 Authorization Server = loop

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to use Spring Authorization Server with Spring Cloud Gateway, but I'm stuck on getting user information. I can see in gateway logs messages like

`[2020-03-23 13:36:35,061] TRACE org.springframework.web.HttpLogging  - [45961b04] Decoded [{access_token=5b5a13f1-2b47-4739-bda2-74785f6e3828, token_type=bearer, expires_in=33556, scope=read}]`

Which means authorization works fine, but after 302 FOUND Location: /res (protected resource) it forwards me back to authorization server.

Full code is in demo project here: https://github.com/looksworking/gw-oauth

**Authorization Server:**

[build.gradle.kts](https://github.com/looksworking/gw-oauth/blob/master/auth/build.gradle.kts)

[application.yml](https://github.com/looksworking/gw-oauth/blob/master/auth/src/main/resources/application.yml)

[WebSecurityConfig](https://github.com/looksworking/gw-oauth/blob/master/auth/src/main/kotlin/org/looksworking/gw/auth/conf/WebSecurityConfig.kt)

[AuthZServerConfig](https://github.com/looksworking/gw-oauth/blob/master/auth/src/main/kotlin/org/looksworking/gw/auth/conf/AuthZServerConfig.kt)

**Spring Cloud Gateway:**

[build.gradle.kts](https://github.com/looksworking/gw-oauth/blob/master/gateway/build.gradle.kts)

[application.yml](https://github.com/looksworking/gw-oauth/blob/master/gateway/src/main/resources/application.yml)

[GatewayApplication](https://github.com/looksworking/gw-oauth/blob/master/gateway/src/main/kotlin/org/looksworking/gw/gateway/GatewayApplication.kt)

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gateway cannot get user info from authorization server to create principal. So, it redirects again to authorization server due to lack of principal. Try to create custom userinfo endpoint in authorization server. (/userinfo instead of /oauth/userinfo). You maybe need to permit /userinfo in security configuration.

```
@RestController
public class UserInfoEndpoint {

    @PostMapping("/userinfo")
    public Map<String, Object> user() {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        String name = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
        map.put("user_name", name);
        return map;
    }

}
```

Also, add *user-info-authentication-method: form* to your provider.

Comment: You are definitely right - I was missing that endpoint, I added it, and I also added UAA server into the project so I can switch from 100% working oauth server to mine. When I switch to UAA, I can see in logs gateway making GET to /userinfo. I added this endpoint, but I still get this loop and I don't see any /userinfo request in logs when I switch to my Authorization Server. Updated github project accordingly.

Comment: first, let's make sure you add gw-oauth-auth to local dns (/etc/host). if not, change them with 172.10.16.1 in gateway provider yml. second, you created endpoint in auth server. it returns "user_name" in map, but you set "user-name-attribute: sub" in gateway. change to user_name or change sub in return statement in auth. also, you dont need check-token-uri and jwk-set-uri properties in provider. one more. your redirect-uri is missing registration id. set to  redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"  .

Comment: Yep, a bit messed up with names while trying everything, and you were right about the main reason in my case - no registration id in redirect-uri. Thank you so much for your time!